# Spring Boot with Spnego/Kerberos - Config Issues - A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, kerberos, spnego

I appear to have hit a bit of a dead-end with getting spring-security-kerberos-web to work with a Spring Boot application.

I have a single @Configuration class in my project as below

```
package com.co.dept.bsc.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosClient;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import com.co.dept.bsc.service.DummyUserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthProviderConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(spnegoEntryPoint()).and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home")
            .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(authenticationManagerBean()), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
            .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosAuthenticationProvider kerberosAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosAuthenticationProvider();
        SunJaasKerberosClient client = new SunJaasKerberosClient();
        client.setDebug(true);
        provider.setKerberosClient(client);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
        return new SpnegoEntryPoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
        final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider() {
        KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider provider = new KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setTicketValidator(sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator());
        provider.setUserDetailsService(dummyUserDetailsService());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator sunJaasKerberosTicketValidator() {
        SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator ticketValidator = new SunJaasKerberosTicketValidator();
        ticketValidator.setServicePrincipal("HTTP/dept-local.uk.hibm.co@HBEU.ADROOT.co");
        ticketValidator.setKeyTabLocation(new FileSystemResource("c:\\Temp\\dept-local.keytab"));
        ticketValidator.setDebug(true);
        return ticketValidator;
    }

    @Bean
    public DummyUserDetailsService dummyUserDetailsService() {
        return new DummyUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig() {
        GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalConfig = new GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig();
        globalConfig.setDebug(true);
        globalConfig.setKrbConfLocation("c:\\Temp\\krb5-local.conf");
        return globalConfig;
    }

}
```

Originally I was seeing an error once I tried to access a secured page after server start up as below..

```
2017-01-18 13:24:39.382  WARN 17848 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.a.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Negotiate Header was invalid: 
Negotiate YIIdDAYGKwYBBQUCoIIdADCCHPygMDAuBgkqhkiC9xIBAgIGCSqGSIb3EgECAgYKKwYBBAGCNwICHgYKKwYBBAGCNwICCqKCHMYEghzCYIIcvgYJKoZIhvcSAQICAQBughytMIIcqaADAgEFoQMCAQ6iBwMFACAAAACjghtCYYIbPjCCGzqgAwIBBaESGxBIQkVVLkFEUk9PVC5IU0JDoiswKaADAgECoSIwIBsESFRUUBsYZ2JnY2YtbG9jYWwudWsuaGlibS5oc2Jjo4Ia8DCCGuygAwIBF6EDAgEDooIa3gSCGtrQN86Xgm7rEcks9wpcZI+KUpVeAC+yG2piTtHszQ9vjRYFC3bcSSqgecgdl .... //Token truncated to save characters

org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceRequestToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:227) ~[spring-security-core-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.kerberos.web.authentication.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:145) ~[spring-security-kerberos-web-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar:1.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.1.1.RELEASE.jar:4.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_40]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [na:1.7.0_40]
```

I noticed that I wasnt configuring the location of the krb5.conf file anywhere so added the bean declaration below into my config class

```
@Bean
    public GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig() {
        GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalConfig = new GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig();
        globalConfig.setDebug(true);
        globalConfig.setKrbConfLocation("c:\\Temp\\krb5-local.conf");
        return globalConfig;
    }
```

Now I get an error on server startup as below

```
2017-01-18 13:27:06.235 ERROR 9108 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at com.co.gbgcf.bsc.BscApplication.main(BscApplication.java:22) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:456) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4efef2c4.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$35(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4efef2c4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ff9b3b82.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4efef2c4.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_40]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

From what I can gather, it may be an issue with the order of bean instantiation in my config class, but I'm not exactly sure where or how to resolve this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

**Solution**

So I managed to resolve this issue with two changes

First in my AuthProviderConfig class I replaced

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
            .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
    }
```

with

```
 @Autowired
public void configureGlobal(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(kerberosAuthenticationProvider())
        .authenticationProvider(kerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

Secondly I extracted

```
@Bean
    public GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig() {
        GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalConfig = new GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig();
        globalConfig.setDebug(true);
        globalConfig.setKrbConfLocation("c:\\Temp\\krb5-local.conf");
        return globalConfig;
    }

        }
```

Into a separate @Configuration class as below

```
package com.co.dept.bsc.kerberos.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.sun.GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig;

/**
 * <p>
 * <b> Additional Configuration for Kerberos. Specifically location of the
 * krb5.conf file This configuration must be in a separate configuration file
 * to the main kerbneros config to prevent instantiation ordering issues</b>
 * </p>
 */

    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(KerberosProperties.class)
    public class GlobalSecurityConfig {

        @Autowired
        private KerberosProperties kerberosProperties;



 @Bean
        public GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalSunJaasKerberosConfig() {
            GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig globalConfig = new GlobalSunJaasKerberosConfig();
            globalConfig.setDebug(true);
            globalConfig.setKrbConfLocation("c:\\Temp\\krb5-local.conf");
            return globalConfig;
        }
    }
```

So the issue was related to the ordering of instantiation of the various beans and servlet container and the two fixes above resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone else!

**UPDATE**

The KerberosProperties class is just a convenience class to hold the properties from **application.properties** file for the Kerberos config details...

```
@ConfigurationProperties("kerberos")
public class KerberosProperties {

    private String krb5Location;
    private String keyTabLocation;
    private String servicePrincipal;

    /**
     * @return the krb5Location
     */
    public String getKrb5Location() {
        return this.krb5Location;
    }

    /**
     * @param krb5Location
     *            the krb5Location to set
     */
    public void setKrb5Location(final String krb5Location) {
        this.krb5Location = krb5Location;
    }

    /**
     * @return the keyTabLocation
     */
    public String getKeyTabLocation() {
        return this.keyTabLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param keyTabLocation
     *            the keyTabLocation to set
     */
    public void setKeyTabLocation(final String keyTabLocation) {
        this.keyTabLocation = keyTabLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the servicePrincipal
     */
    public String getServicePrincipal() {
        return this.servicePrincipal;
    }

    /**
     * @param servicePrincipal
     *            the servicePrincipal to set
     */
    public void setServicePrincipal(final String servicePrincipal) {
        this.servicePrincipal = servicePrincipal;
    }
}
```

and my **application.properties** file has properties like

```
kerberos.krb5Location=c:\\Temp\\krb5-local.conf
kerberos.keyTabLocation=c:\\Temp\\dept-local.keytab
kerberos.servicePrincipal=HTTP/dept-local.uk.hibm.co@HBEU.ADROOT.CO
```

so these just replace the hard coded values I was using orginially

Comment: This issue was solved with Spring Boot 2.0.0.M4 - but in a way, wich will break this solution. So you will have to revert to the original solution, since Spring Boot will now only create a single AuthManager.

Answer (score 2):

I've now resolved this issue with two minor changes to resolve an issue with the order in which objects were instantiated. See the update to the original queestion marked **Solution**

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Hi, thanks for this info, but do you have a sketch of what DummyUserDetailsService looks like?

Comment: @ChrisWolf
`import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;`

Comment: `public class DummyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
 @Override
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
  return new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
 }

}`